# svn - file-based revision number instead of the repo

Tags: svn, version-control, revision

Is there any way I can keep the revision number incremented on each single file, instead of on the whole repository? A simpler way to put it is probably the number of commits of a file.

SVN does this for me:

1. two files under a repo: a.txt, b.txt
2. commit a.txt, the revision comes to 1
3. commit b.txt, the revision comes to 2
4. commit a.txt one more time, the revision comes to 3

What I think is more convenient is in step 4, the revision should be 2, because it refer to "the second commit of a.txt"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do it in SVN (by design). Independent version of single and every file in repository was implemented and used in CVS - and globally abandoned later in favor of the concept of global revisions with the scope "Repository"

Your file-revision definition:

- Have minimal value for any real task
- Can be easy obtained on the fly from existing metadata

**Do not reinvent the wheel!!!**